# Shapefile misforming when overlaid on map

Tags: shapefile, ggmap

I thought I was attempting something pretty simple - adding a shapefile over a terrain map. This is how the image looks when the shapefile is added to Google Earth:

[image]

However, when I process the data through R, I get the following image (this is just part of the picture, showing how the shapefile is different:

[image]

Some aspects of the shapefile are preserved, but some regions are inverted, and I'm not sure what's causing these problems. This is the code I'm using to process the file:

```
PPR -> readOGR("Wetland_Files/PPR_Extent/", "PPRboundary")
PPR -> spTransform(PPR, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
PPR -> fortify(PPR)
ggmap(myMap) + geom_polygon(aes(x = long, + y = lat, + group = group), + data = PPR, +  color = "white", + fill = "orange", + alpha = 0.5) + labs(x = "Longitude", + y = "Latitude")
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to what is going on here?

Comment: Do you have all the data in one file or in several files?

Comment: Yes, all the data is in one file.

Comment: Whenever I see weird behavior like this I check my geometry.  ArcGIS Repair geometry tool; QGIS check validity.